# iMessage and FaceTime not working after changing apple id

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, messages, facetime

Last time I got macbook and iphone from my brother. These devices were always connected with one apple id. I wanted to keep all apps and settings, so I did not create new apple id, I've just changed password, email, name of current apple id, so now it is only mine, not my broter's. 
And I don't know why, but imessage and facetime not working, on both devices. I can log in icloud, and everything if fine, but when I'm trying to log in on imessage or face time this appears :

> "An error occurred during activation"

Before change everything worked.
I have tried almost everything. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to tell what could be the problem without knowing what happed exactly. You can use below link to check some solutions to your problem. If that wasn't help I suggest to contact apple support team.

https://support.apple.com/en-lk/HT201422

Comment: Thank You, but I have tried all of this. Didn't help.

Comment: Then it's better to at least make a chat with Apple support team. Almost every time I got a problem they solve it within minutes. So strongly suggest to contact them. :)